# Javascript Returning values with Form Optgroup parent

Tags: javascript, html, queue, optgroup

I would like to return the option values selected in a multiple option select box
It works it I do not have a optgroup tags in. As soon as I add in the these tags, I cannot get the child values. I am sure this is a noddy question but I cannot find the correct syntax to get the correct array which is **dropdown.options**

```js
$('#mydropdown option').click(function(evt) {
  var selectedOption = evt.target;
  var dropdown = this.parentNode;
  queue.add(selectedOption.value);
  Array.from(dropdown.options).forEach(function(option) {
    if (!option.selected) {
      queue.remove(option.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mydropdown" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="optionx Fruits" selected>Fruits</option>
    <option value="optionx Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="optionx Nuts">Nuts</option>
    <option value="optionx Meats">Meats</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: I fixed the snippet What is queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just create a new set each time

This is important if you want the set to contain only selected ones.

If you want the set to contain what the user selected and KEEP it when the user unselect, then just add

Also notice I trigger the change to initialise the set when loading

```js
let queue;
$('#mydropdown').on("change", function(evt) {
  queue = new Set();
  $("option:selected",this).each(function() { queue.add(this.value) });
  console.log("changed -------")
  for (const item of queue) console.log(item)
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mydropdown" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="optionx Fruits" selected>Fruits</option>
    <option value="optionx Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="optionx Nuts">Nuts</option>
    <option value="optionx Meats">Meats</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

IF you want to keep the order selected, you will indeed need to just add and then remove

```js
let queue = new Set();

$('#mydropdown').on("click", function(evt) {
  $(this).find("option").each(function() {
    queue.add(this.value); 
    if (!this.selected) queue.delete(this.value)
  })
  console.log("changed -------")
  for (const item of queue) console.log(item)
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mydropdown" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="optionx Fruits" selected>Fruits</option>
    <option value="optionx Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="optionx Nuts">Nuts</option>
    <option value="optionx Meats">Meats</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. I have used the latter one.

Comment: top man...how good are you sir! <3

Comment: sorry If click fruit then vegetables, vegatables doesn't show. It works other way around though

Comment: Can you explain the exact sequence, because I cannot reproduce. Note that fruits are already selected and in the set at load time

Comment: ok so if you click vegetables and then select fruits then  ctrl +veg then only fruits appears

Comment: Fixed the second code

Comment: Bingo. Thanks my friend. You are the man!

Answer (score 0):

On click your parentnode becomes optgroup

```
var dropdown = this.parentNode;
```

so you should set

```
var dropdown = this.parentNode.parentNode;
```